# LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: connect: timeout error

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I am trying to configure `aws cloudwatch` script for monitoring memory etc. While executing the script we get below error and I upgraded the `perl` package the LWP version is also latest as 6 but still script is failing with below error.

I tried setting env variables as  `PERL_LWP_ENV_PROXY=1`  and  `PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME=0` but still failing. Please help on this.

> [ec2-user@ip-10-175-82-195 aws-scripts-mon]$ sudo
>   ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail
>   --aws-credential-file=./awscreds.template
>
> ERROR: Failed to call CloudWatch: HTTP 500. Message: Can't connect to
>   monitoring.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 (timeout)
>
> LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: connect: timeout at
>   /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 47.
>
> For more information, run 'mon-put-instance-data.pl --help'

Comment: For reference, the scripts are available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/mon-scripts.html FWIW, I do not see anything in the stock modules and scripts that force the use of `Crypt::SSLeay`. Remember, even installing the current `Crypt::SSLeay` opts you in to use `IO::Socket::SSL` (and, by extension, `Net::SSLeay`). See https://www.nu42.com/2014/04/does-your-code-really-depend-on.html

Answer (score 2):

> `PERL_LWP_ENV_PROXY=1`

I guess this also means that you have the `http_proxy` environment variable set to a proxy it should use and that there is no way to the target except by using this proxy.

> `$ sudo ./mon-put-instance-data.pl`

Calling something using sudo will run it with different privileges. For security reasons the environment variables are heavily scrubbed before by sudo before calling the program which probably means that `http_proxy` is empty for the program run by sudo. This again means that it will try to reach the target site directly instead of using a proxy and will timeout on connection since the site can only be reached using the proxy.

Comment: I tried running the script as root after exporting PERL_LWP_ENV_PROXY=1 and I am getting the below error.

Comment: [root@ip-10-175-82-195 aws-scripts-mon]# ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --aws-credential-file=/root/.aws/awscreds

ERROR: Failed to call CloudWatch: HTTP 500. Message: SSL negotiation failed:  at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 27.
 at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 27.
;  at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 27.
;  at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 27.

For more information, run 'mon-put-instance-data.pl --help'

Comment: @Keeplearning: This is a different problem and the original one (timeout) is obviously fixed since it successfully established a TCP connection to the server and only failed in the SSL handshake. Therefore please ask a new question and include the details needed to help with this new question (i.e. code, debug output when run with `-MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4`, ...)

Comment: Ok I will create a new question

Comment: @Keeplearning: don't forget to accept a correct answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Steffen, I tried clicking the answer but its not allowing since I am a new user. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be build-essential is not installed.
Please install the build essentials. I faced the same issue. Once build- essential installed , install all the related cpan module.

sudo apt-get install build-essential

Thanks 
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
yum install openssl openssl-devel
perl -MCPAN -e 'install LWP::Protocol::https'
```

If the issue persists, try

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::CPAN'
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::LWP5_837'
```